# Add daterange to Google Search Appliance without displaying daterange in input

Tags: google-search-appliance

I'm using the GSA Iframe and I have a date selection that the user can choose the date range. Is there a way to add the daterange without changing the value of the user's query? I know I can add daterange:YYYY-MM-DD..YYY-MM-DD to the query input box right before the user clicks submit but I don't want it to appear in the input box. I thought I could add a hidden input field named 'daterange' with the date value but that doesn't seem to work.

Update: I have tried adding as_q as a hidden form element. This does work but seems to also add the date to the input box.

I also tried adding daterange hidden form field and modifying the xslt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the as_q parameter?
http://www.google.com/support/enterprise/static/gsa/docs/admin/72/gsa_doc_set/xml_reference/request_format.html

Comment: Thanks @BigMikeW. I did see as_q after I posted my question and it does also work but it seems to get added to the input box upon return of the results. I also tried adding <input type="hidden" name="daterange" value="{PARAM[@name='daterange']/@value}" /> in the XSLT

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing is creating my own variable in the XSLT that holds the query parameter and then setting that as the input value only.